# Perl: closing child process fails when file handle to child/pipe is aliased

Tags: perl, pipe, alias

I've read all the perl documentation on open, close and IPC and read a number of related forum threads, but still have been unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  To start with I created this simple forked process to prove that I did the open handling correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Handle;
my $pid = open(CHILD, "|-");
if ($pid == 0) {
    # child:
    while (<STDIN>) { # keeps reading until parent closes it's end of the pipe
        chomp $_;
        print "child: $_\n";
    }
}
else {
    # parent:
    for my $line (1..3) {
        print CHILD "$line\n";
    }
    my $success = close CHILD;
    print "parent: success: $success, \$!: $!, \$?: $?\n";
}
```

The output, as expected, is:

```
child: 1
child: 2
child: 3
parent: success: 1, $!: Illegal seek, $?: 0
```

The success value is true; so I just ignore the 'Illegal seek' as it's not relevant, supposedly.  However, when I alias STDOUT to the pipe (to avoid needing to print explicitly to CHILD) and then later revert STDOUT back to it's original value, as follows, the close CHILD no longer works (even though STDOUT is no longer pointing to it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Handle;
my $pid = open(CHILD, "|-");
if ($pid == 0) {
    # child:
    while (<STDIN>) { # keeps reading until parent closes it's end of the pipe
        chomp $_;
        print "child: $_\n";
    }
}
else {
    # parent:
    open(ORIG_STDOUT, ">&STDOUT") or die "Unable to dup STDOUT: $!";
    open(STDOUT, ">&=CHILD")      or die "Unable to alias CHILD: $!";
    for my $line (1..3) {
        print "$line\n";
    }
    open(STDOUT, ">&=ORIG_STDOUT") or die "Unable to alias ORIG_STDOUT: $!";
    my $success = close CHILD;
    print "parent: success: $success, \$!: $!, \$?: $?\n";
}
```

The output is this:

```
child: 1
child: 2
child: 3
parent: success: , $!: Illegal seek, $?: -1
```

The success value is no longer true, which means that either there was an error in closing the pipe, or the CHILD returned a non-zero value.  The -1 value of $? indicates that the wait system call failed for some reason and I'm not sure what the "Illegal seek" means, but the fact that $! was not zero, further indicates that it was not just the CHILD process returning a non-zero code that made the close CHILD return false, but rather that there was some kind of error in the closing procedure.  What am I missing here?

Comment: CHILD is special because it also acts as a handle to the child. Using `>&=` appears to mess things up. Duping the handle (`>&`) instead copying its fd (`>&=`) works

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems. First, your call to `open` is actually failing in both programs, or rather it does if you append the check clause after the first call.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Handle;

my $pid = open(CHILD, "|-") or die("A descriptive message");
```

The program immediately crashes upon execution. However, since the pipe in the open-mode argument implies a call to `fork`, this means there are supposed to be two separate processes worth of total output. Understandably, you assumed the call succeeded, since code after that point was being executed.

The reason the call to `open` failed, however, is multi-faceted and interesting. You're passing in an invalid file descriptor, but something really interesting would happen if the child process could live long enough to try to duplicate the file descriptor. Using `">&="` instead of simply `">&"` in the call to `open` changes the underlying call to the kernel from `dup` to `fdopen`; the first returns a file *descriptor* and the second a file *handle*. (In C: `int` vs `FILE*`)

TL;DR: You're not duplicating the file descriptor because you said you didn't want to duplicate the file descriptor, and the seek error was the logical consequence of attempting to read `1 + n` bytes past the `0` total bytes of the null handle you received from the call to `open`.